# Sms Receiver NOT working

Tags: android, xml, sms

I followed a tutorial on Receiving sms using BroadcastReceiver

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-zYXVODiPo

I used exactly the same codes. Enabled Telnet client. Does my device need to be rooted first? I don't know the problem. Please help.

Here's my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BroadcastReceiver receiver;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arr0, Intent arr1) {
                processReceiver(arr0,arr1);

            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);


    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    public void processReceiver(Context context,Intent intent){
        Toast.makeText(context,"RECEIVED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextView lbs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] objArr = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        String sms="";



        for(int i=0;i>objArr.length;i++){
            SmsMessage smsMsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])objArr[i]);
            String smsBody = smsMsg.getMessageBody();
            String senderNumber = smsMsg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            sms+= "From: "+senderNumber+"\nContent: "+smsBody+"\n";
        }
        lbs.setText(sms);
    }
```

Here's my Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gavadev.com.smsreceiver">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Instead of copying the code and expecting it to work by copying and pasting, try understanding what you are doing... otherwise it will never work. You need to understand the code otherwise you can't debug it. Learn to read code and documentation. Also note that you have to be in your Activity to receive the message as you register your receiver in the onCreate

Comment: I do trace its algorithm and I tried coding my own but I've tested multiple times and nothing worked. So I copied this and tested, still didn't worked.

Comment: Also it depends on what device/version you're running on and how exactly you're validating that it "works".

Comment: Your receiver will not work if MainActivity is destroyed. That is you can not exit from this activity and can not go to another activity.

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury so should i remove it?

Comment: Use a Broadcast Receiver which is registered via manifest file instead of local broadcast receiver.

Comment: I updated an answer. You can try it...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Broadcast Receiver which will not be unregistered when destroying the activity:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
    {
        // your processing will go here...
    }

}

}
```

Register the receiver via manifest file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.broadcastreceiverpremier"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.broadcastreceiverpremier.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: thanks!..is it ok if the <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> is not suggested?like the suggested ones are only android.intent.SOMETHING?